# Is a loop to send lots of emails in PHP (Laravel) really such a bad idea?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send lots of emails, I know there are great services such as MailChimp but, right now, the project doesn't generate enough incomes to pay that.

I've tried this solution and it works. Beside the time (+15 min. for each 1k emails. Can be improved, like sending 10 emails at the time, i.e.) what are the real down sides of this:

```
// This is to allows script running "in the background"
// and allow the user to close the browser
ob_start();
echo "Sending emails";
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Encoding: none");
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
header("Connection: close");
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
if(session_id()) session_write_close();

// Start the background work here.

for ($i=0 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++)
{
    Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new Test($i));
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: yes it is.. use jobs instead

Comment: Ok, but the job would be loop into all the email address and send them? Is that what you mean?

Comment: What respectable business requires to send thousands of emails all day long without producing some revenue? Sorry, but I doubt many people here will try to help you with this. It smells to much of a SPAM business...

Comment: You can try php gearman.

Comment: why would you do a loop? is the event triggered to all users?

Comment: I understand your worry, but I'm from Venezuela, it is incredibly difficult to produce dollars because of our inflation problems. The project produces our currency, which is nothing when you pass it to dollars. But thanks anyway for your concerns. @arkascha

Comment: @jycr753 I want, for example, to send an email to all the users from time to time. That's why I was thinking to loop into all the users in the DB table.

Comment: ah okay if it is like that dont not need an loop like this.... you can write an command that gets all users that match your criteria, this commands adds the emails to the jobs queue.. and you run this command using the scheduler.. makes sense?

Comment: Well, @jycr753 not right now tbh. But you definitely said some things to look into. So, thanks! You pointed the road.